# Test design and test case specification

Tags: testing

Hey,
can someone tell me what is differences between test design and test case specification? I use IEEE 829 Test Case Specification Template and I'm not sure where should I write steps for testing
Thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Test Design Specification:**
detailing test conditions and the expected results as well as test pass criteria
**Test Case Specification:** 
specifying the test data for use in running the test conditions identified in the Test Design Specification

Comment: There are many examples and sources on web that have expected results in the Test Case Specification. Also according to the ISTQB that refers to TCS I would say that it is not in TDS.

Answer (score 1):

In IEEE 829, each numbered "Test Design Specification" section defines a feature set to be tested and the general criteria to determine pass/fail of its test cases. It also must list the ids of the test case specifications which implement its test requirements. There many be many TDS sections in a test plan. For example, you would have one TDS for each use case and alternate flow to be tested.

Each numbered "Test Case Specification" defines the exact setup and inputs for one test case. So there are typically many TCS for each TDS.

As a practical matter, expected results are typically required for each test case, instead of general, TDS-level criteria. Putting the criteria in the TDS is usually done to support manual testing and allowing the tester to make subjective evaluations, using general knowledge.

This supports a complete hierarchy of feature sets to test and their test cases. It works equally well for manual and automated testing, and at unit, integration, or system scope.

Answer (score 1):

- Test Design Specifications:
  The objective of compiling test design specifications is to identify set of features or a combination of features to be tested and to identify the group of test cases that will adequately test those features. In addition to these it contains all types of refinements done to the approach described in the test plan.

The test design specification consists of following essential parts:

1) Test design specification identifier: A unique identifier is to be allocated so that the test design specification document can be distinguished from all other documents.

2) Features to be tested: It describes the test items and the features that are the object of this test design specification.

3) Approach refinements: It describes the test techniques to be adopted for this test design.

4) Test identification: It describes a comprehensive list of test cases associated with this test design. It provides a unique identifier and a short description for every test case.

5) Acceptance criteria: It describes the criteria to confirm as to whether each feature has passed or failed during testing.

- Test Case Specifications:
  The objective of compiling the test case specifications is to specify in detail each test case listed in the test design specification.

The test case specification consists of following essential parts:

1) Test case specification identifier: A unique identifier so that this document can be distinguished from all other documents.

2) Test items: Identifies the items and features to be tested by the particular test case.

3) Input specifications: It describes details of each & every input required by the particular test case.

4) Output specifications: It describes each output expected after executing the particular test case.

5) Environmental needs: It describes any special hardware, software, facilities, etc. required for the execution of the particular test case that were not listed in its associated test design specification.

6) Special procedural requirements: It describes any special setup, execution, or cleanup procedures unique to the particular test case.

7) Inter-case dependencies: It describes a comprehensive list of all test cases that must be executed prior to the particular test case.